# How do i connect to a private host using a public host?

Tags: networking, ssh, server

Server B is connected to a private network at , say , 192.168.1.130.
Server A can be connected using ssh using its public ip ; 132.x.x.x.
How would i connect to B using ssh such that it first connects to A from which a connection to B is established as B cannot be directly connected to from an outside network.
What I want to restrict myself from doing is:
**user@local**:$ssh a@A

**a@A** : $ssh b@B

Rather I'm looking for doing something along the lines of:

**user@local**: $ssh b@B

which internally connects to a@A and then b@B.

How would I implement this for a set of ubuntu servers?

I have tried editing **~/.ssh/config** to include

```
 Host A
    User a
    HostName 192.x.x.x
 Host B
    User b
    ProxyCommand ssh -q A nc -q0 192.x.x.x 22
```

When running b@B from "a@A" gets me the desired output which is connect to b through a (though quite pointless). How do I achieve this for a user on whose system it would be impossible to edit the config file or something similar.

PS: A has a **public** ip while B is restricted to **private** ip.

Edit : edited the example code to correctly imply what I'm trying to mean

Comment: What I want to achieve is tell the world , that if you want access to B use "ssh b@B" . I don't want to tell them about server A in itself, rather I want server A to automatically redirect the user requesting access to B automatically through A .Also what I have is A and B both point to the same host ie A . Therefore a@B is the same as a@A.

Answer (score 1):

Preferred way of using `ProxyCommand` is with `-W` switch. `nc` version requires to have `netcat` installed on the jumpbox.

```
 Host A
    User a
    HostName 192.x.x.x
 Host B
    User b
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p A
```

And note that letter case matters! You have there upper case user in your example. Also do not put there `-q` switch until you know it works fine. It it does not, add some `-vvv` to both `ssh` commands to see what is going on there and what fails.

Comment: Ah, quite interesting, I wasn't aware SSH now embeds netcat functionality for this purpose. Cool feature! (Though I wonder if it has any interesting security implications...)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently ProxyCommand can be passed on commandline via `-o`; not too pretty, but seems like the intended method.

See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

As a note though, I think you might have gotten which of A/B is public/private backwards, since your initial paragraph seems to contradict your final statement.

More details on the exact solution http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/ with diagrams.

Comment: '$ ssh -tt A ssh -tt B' 

works just fine and does the job that is required by me.
However is a command possible that does the same as the one above just, without listing A. Also, as a requirement it could be possible to have B point to A's IP address also . Though my main requirement is tunneling to B through A

Comment: Ah; that sounds like you have some incompatible requirements though, like (1) not editing the config file at all, and (2) not listing A in the commandline. In this case, unless you have a script or something which does list A, SSH has no way to know about host A as far as I can tell.

Comment: Say user x is connecting from a public ip and he wishes to connect to host B; what i need is him typing ssh b@B . B however shares the same IP as A. ie. they both get redirected to a@A . The system A then knows that the request is not coming for it but instead to host B and then redirects the user x to host B or b@B.

Comment: Also it is possible for me to set the same user a on both A and B so a@A and a@B is valid. I'm also free to modify any file on system A to allow for this redirection. Could such a use case be possible such that x can only type in a@B or b@B and be redirected successfully to host B?

Comment: B is something like xyz.com pointing to IP 139.x.x.x 
and A is something like abc.com also pointing to IP 139.x.x.x.
However B has a private ip also say 192.x.x.x. Is such a redirection possible.
This is a continuation for the previous two comments; just elaborating my requirement further.

Comment: As far as both the links are concerned I can and I have successfully achieved it using "$ ssh -tt A ssh -tt B" . I just need to eliminate the need to tell user x about system A.

Comment: Can you put your SSH service on A on a different port, and have port 22 auto-forward to B? Note that SSH doesn't send the host name on a connection request, so if both hostnames point at the same IP, the connection request is _indistinguishable_ from the server's point of view. You should choose how you want to distinguish the two connection types: different sockets/ports, different usernames, different commands.